# How to read number of FATs from FAT filesystem?

Tags: c, filesystems, fat

I'm trying to read the number of FATs my FAT filesystem might have. In order to do that I'm reading as reference the documentation found [here](https://d1.amobbs.com/bbs_upload782111/files_1/armok0123302.pdf).

It's said that the number of FATs is given in the 16th byte of the binary file. But it has a length of 1 byte. From my knowledge, I know integers are at least 4 bytes long.

How can I read the number of FATs in my binary file?

I have tried reading it anyways without success:

```
void test(int file_descriptor) {
    int nFats;

    lseek(file_descriptor, 16, SEEK_SET);
    read(file_descriptor, &nFats, 1);

    printf("Number of FATs: %d\n", nFats);
}
```

Comment: Well a single unsigned byte will give you a number from 0 to 255. I guess it's enough for the number of FATs. Use `uint8_t`.

Comment: Hint: `unsigned char` is an integer type.

Comment: Have a look at `stdint.h`

Comment: You might like to define a (packed) structure of the boot sector to access such information.It will help you also in any other work with the filesystem.